# Clean transition for a searchbar navigationBar

Tags: ios, swift

I have a navigationbar where I have the searchbar as the title view. The problem arises when I want to transition to the next viewController.

As you can see, the transtion is done in such a way that the navigationBar is not change at all, but only the viewController is slide in.. as shown in the pics below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

This transition introduces some unexpected result.. for example, the back-arrow becomes coated in a white layer which the original image does not have.

After wards, I check out other apps.. I realise that the transition in other apps for a navigationbar that contains a searchbar is done difference...

For example, in facebook, the entire viewController including the navigationbar is replaced, as shown below.

[image]

[image]

the transition is too fast for me to capure, but you can try to do the search in the facebook and see taht the entire viewcontroller including the navigationbar is swiped out.

Anyone knows how to achieve something like this?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you need a searchBar for both view controller?

Comment: @Mannopson nope, I dont need .

Comment: What's the problem itself? It's a `searchBar`? It's won't disappear?

Comment: @Mannopson the transition itself... I want something like what is done in facebook..

Comment: something like a horizontal modal presentation

Comment: This is not a horizontal presentation. It's a custom transition

Answer (score 0):

In the `viewController` that has the search bar, use the following `deinit` method

```
deinit {
    if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
        searchController.loadViewIfNeeded()
    } else {
        let _ = searchController.view
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is a presentation context! Try something like this:

```
self.definePresentationContext = true
```

Put this line of code to the SearchBarOwnerViewController's `viewDidLoad`.